# Get location of address

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit

Is there a way I can get the latitude/longitude of a location based on an address? I know this can be done using Google APIs but is there something built into Cocoa-Touch that will allow me to do this so I don't have to handle all the networking/parsing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to think of ways of extending this answer - but simply put, No.  There is not an native cocoa-touch API to do what you want.

Have you seen the Google Maps API for objective-c : [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this](http://g-off.net/software/cllocation-forward-geolocation-method)???

I've read it once, but I have not test it yet.